# Защита админ панели

Tags: php, laravel

Пишу проект с админ панелью на Laravel 5.2.

`/*` — сам сайт
`/admin/*` — панель администратора

На сайте не предусмотрена авторизация пользователей.

Как защитить админ панель? Само собой, ssl покупать придется. Есть вариант с .htaccess, чтобы прописать IP, которым будет дан доступ к `/admin`.

Как лучше сделать? Расскажите о плюсах и минусах предложенных решений...

Answer (score 1):

Если не предусмотренна авторизация можете создать `Middleware` с прверкой по IP
в app/http/Middlware создаёте файлы IpMiddleware (или любоей другое название)

```
namespace App\Http\Middleware;
use Closure;
class IpMiddleware{
      public function handle($request, Closure $next)
     {
         if($request->ip() != 'Доверенный ИП'){
              //ИП не соответсвует
              return abort(401);
         }
         //всё впорядке ИП ваш
         return $next($request);
     }
}
```

Потом в `app/http/Kernel.php` дописываете d $routeMiddleware массив

```
'ipcheck' => \App\Http\Middleware\IpMiddleware::class,
```

Теперь можете его использовать на Руты или в КОнтроллере

```
Route::get('admin', ['middleware' => 'ipcheck', function()
{
    //
}]);
```

Или в контроллере

```
public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('ipcheck')
    }
```

Это с помощью Laravel ещё можно использовать`basicAuth`

Или средставим [Апачи](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/auth.html)

Какой лучше. Я думаю всё таки лучше закрыть доступ через Апач чтоб можно было вводить Пароль и Логин ну а также дополнительно привязать Laravel к Ip!

Comment: очень интересно про Apache auth, обязательно почитаю) Но про ip кстати, как по мне, так не очень то и дельный способ, хоть и надежный. Трудности составляет то, что у людей которым будет дан доступ в админ панель может быть динамический ip + надо править список ip, если добавляется новый человек в команде админов к примеру. Еще нашел способ двусторонней аутентификации через google authenticator. Интересно будет выслушать Ваше мнение по ней.

Comment: Google Auth Очень хорошая штука сам использую на всех проектах. Выбор большой))) я предпочитаю делть всё, чтоб наверняка))))

С другой стороноы вы можете просто создать `Permissions` Larave поддерживает из коробки, если нет есть модуль для Laravel 5+ `Cartalyst Sentinel` Там можно создовать группы и так далее. И вы так же сможете создать Middleware который просто проверяет Группу пользователя.

Answer (score 0):

Авторизацией называют как раз контроль доступа. А ввод имени и пароля это аутентификация.

Проверяйте права текущего пользователя. В Laravel принято выносить фильтры доступа на уровень middleware. Можно привязать такого посредника конкретно к административным маршрутам.

- http://laravel.su/docs/5.0/middleware
- https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/middleware

Comment: формулировка может быть не верная у меня была, по этому немного Вас запутал. Но middleware использовать уже умеем, и будем в ПА(панель администратора). Но вот со стороны сервера может как-то еще защитить можно сам вход в ПА)?

Comment: Можно в конфиге Apache или в .htaccess указать ограничение по IP. Я считаю такое ограничение годным только для общения серверов между собой. А мобильность человека лучше не ограничивать, п.м.с.м.